# Respond with specific cell content in if condition of any specific row and formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to make a spreadsheet on google which will keep the record of tax & vat payment status of our clients. I can receive the record response from "F" & "G" Column with formula. I need to get the Text from "F2" and "G2" cell as a response at Column "C". I have tried and done a lot of brainstorming but I've finished with this formula till now on:

=IF(SUM(F2:G2)+1-1>0,DATA AVAIL)

=IF(SUM(F3:G3)+1-1>0,DATA AVAIL)

=IF(SUM(F4:G4)+1-1>0,DATA AVAIL)

=IF(SUM(F5:G5)+1-1>0,DATA AVAIL)

But I Need to Response with Cell "F2" & "G2" Text. Any Cordial co-operation will be happily received and Thanks for spending enough time behind my problem for a solution.

[image: problem that I am trying to solve]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - e.g. what exactly do you mean by these two sentences? "But I need to get the Text from "F1" and "G1" cell as a response at Column "C". "...."But I Need to Response with Cell "F2" & "G2" Text.".  Which one do you need?  what's the problem and why are you summing text labels (or have they been formatted as string but are actually numerical??)

Comment: @JB-007 my mistake, please allow me for correction! "I Need to Response with Cell "F2" & "G2" Text" thanks a lot for your precious time and point me to my mistake!

Comment: np mate - looks like someone's solved below so looking good from here out - have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a couple of if statements like this:

```
=IF(F3<>"",F$2,IF(G3<>"",G$2,""))&IF(AND(F3<>"",G3<>"")," & "&G$2,"")
```

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]